# Closure/Не знаю как написать функцию с замыканием

Tags: javascript, frontend, task, замыкания, closure-compiler

> - Write add function which consumes x as argument (number)
>   and returned other function which consumes y as argument (number)
> - and return the sum of x and y

```
function foo() {
function add(x) {
}} // Upgrade this function
```

> - should summarize two values using closure
> - should sum 3 and 5
>   should sum 4 and 2
>   should sum 9 and -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function add(x) {
    function other(y) {
        return x+y;
    }
    return other;
}
```